# the learning rate change for the momentum optimizer

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

When running an existing Tensorflow implementation, I found that the learning rate keeps the same between different epochs. The original implementations uses `tf.train.MomentumOptimizer`, and has `decay rate` setup.

My understanding for the momentum optimizer is that learning rate should decrease along with the epochs. Why the learning rate keeps the same for my training process. Is that possible that the learning rate will also depend on the performance, e.g., if the performance does not change quickly, then the learning rate will keep the same. I think I am not very clear about the underlying mechanism of momentum optimizer, and feel confused that the learning rate keeps the same along with the epoch even though I guess it should keep decreasing based on the given decay rate.

The optimizer is defined as follows

```
        learning_rate =  0.2
        decay_rate = 0.95            
        self.learning_rate_node = tf.train.exponential_decay(learning_rate=learning_rate, 
                                                    global_step=global_step, 
                                                    decay_steps=training_iters,  
                                                    decay_rate=decay_rate, 
                                                    staircase=True)

        optimizer = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate=self.learning_rate_node).minimize(self.net.cost, 
                                                                            global_step=global_step)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a little bit hard to tell without looking at the code if my answer will be helpful to you or not.

However if you need some insights on how the momentum optimizer works and how the learning rate **should** decay.

1. First the Vanilla `GradientDescentMinimizer`'s update which is the most basic:

   W^(n+1)=W^(n)-alpha*(gradient of cost wrt W)(W^n)

   You are just following the opposite of the gradient.
2. The `GradientDescentMinimizer` with learning rate decay:

   W^(n+1)=W^(n)-alpha(n)*(gradient of the cost wrt W)(W^n)

The only thing that changed is the learning rate alpha , which is now dependent of the step in Tensorflow the most used is the exponential decay where after N step the learning rate is divided by some constant i.e. 10.

This change often happens later in the training so **you might need to let a few epochs pass by before seeing it decay**.

3. The `Momentumoptimizer`:
   you have to keep an additional variable: the update you have done just before i.e you have to store at each time step:

   update^(n)=(W^(n)-W^(n-1))

   Then the corrected update by momentum is:

   update^(n+1)=m*update^(n)-alpha*(gradient of cost wrt W)(W^n)

So what you are doing is doing simple gradient descent but correcting it by remembering the immediate past (There are smarter and more complicated ways of doing it like Nesterov's momentum)

4. `MomentumOptimizer` with learning rate decay:

update^(n)=(W^(n)-W^(n-1))

update^(n+1)=m*update^(n)-alpha(n)*(gradient of cost wrt W)(W^n)

alpha is now dependent of n too.

So at one point it will starts slowing down as in gradient descent with learning rate decay but the decrease will be affected by the momentum.

For a complete review of those methods and more you have [the excellent website](http://sebastianruder.com/optimizing-gradient-descent/) which explains far better than me and [Alec Radford's famous visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZOUf.jpg) which is better than a thousand words.

The learning rate should not depend on the performance unless it is specified in the decay !
It would help to see the code in question !

**EDIT1::** Here is a working example that I think answer both questions you asked:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Pure SGD
BATCH_SIZE=1
#Batch Gradient Descent
#BATCH_SIZE=1000
starter_learning_rate=0.001

xdata=np.linspace(0.,2*np.pi,1000)[:,np.newaxis]
ydata=np.sin(xdata)+np.random.normal(0.0,0.05,size=1000)[:,np.newaxis]
plt.scatter(xdata,ydata)

x=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,1])
y=tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,1])
#We define global_step as a variable initialized at 0
global_step=tf.Variable(0,trainable=False)

w1=tf.Variable(0.05*tf.random_normal((1,100)),tf.float32)
w2=tf.Variable(0.05*tf.random_normal((100,1)),tf.float32)

b1=tf.Variable(np.zeros([100]).astype("float32"),tf.float32)
b2=tf.Variable(np.zeros([1]).astype("float32"),tf.float32)

h1=tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x,w1)+b1)
y_model=tf.matmul(h1,w2)+b2


L=tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_model-y))

#We want to decrease the learning rate after having seen all the data 5 times
NUM_EPOCHS_PER_DECAY=5
LEARNING_RATE_DECAY_FACTOR=0.1
#Since the mechanism of the decay depends on the number of iterations and not epochs we have to connect the number of epochs to the number of iterations

#So if we have batch_size=1 we have to iterate exactly 1000 times to do one epoch so 5*1000=5000 iterations before decaying if the batch_size was 1000 1 iterations=1epoch and thus we decrease it after 5 iterations 
num_batches_per_epoch=int(xdata.shape[0]/float(BATCH_SIZE))
decay_steps=int(num_batches_per_epoch*NUM_EPOCHS_PER_DECAY)
decayed_learning_rate=tf.train.exponential_decay(starter_learning_rate, 
                                                     global_step, 
                                                     decay_steps, 
                                                     LEARNING_RATE_DECAY_FACTOR,
                                                     staircase=True)

#So now we have an object that depends on global_step and that will be divided by 10 every decay_steps iterations i.e. when global_step=N*decay_steps with N a non zero integer         

#We now create a train_step to which we pass the learning rate created each time this function is called global_step will be incremented by 1 we are gonna check that it is the case BE CAREFUL WE HAVE TO GIVE IT GLOBAL_STEP AS AN ARGUMENT
train_step=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(decayed_learning_rate).minimize(L,global_step=global_step)
sess=tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
GLOBAL_s=[]
lr_val=[]
COSTS=[]
for i in range(16000):
    #We will do 1600 iterations so as there is a decay every 5000 iterations we will see 3 decays (5000,10000,15000)
    start_data=(i*BATCH_SIZE)%1000
    COSTS.append([sess.run(L, feed_dict={x:xdata,y:ydata})])
    GLOBAL_s.append([sess.run(global_step)])
    lr_val.append([sess.run(decayed_learning_rate)])
    #I see the train_step as implicitely executing sess.run(tf.add(global_step,1))
    sess.run(train_step,feed_dict={x:xdata[start_data:start_data+BATCH_SIZE],y:ydata[start_data:start_data+BATCH_SIZE]})


plt.figure()
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(GLOBAL_s,lr_val,"-b")
plt.title("Evolution of learning rate" )
plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot(GLOBAL_s,COSTS,".g")
plt.title("Evolution of cost" )



#notice two things first global_step is actually being incremented and learning rate is actually being decayed
```

(You can writeMomentumOptimize() instead of GradientDescentOptimizer() obviously...)

Here are the two plots I get:
[image: Here is the evolution of the global_step parameter and decayed_learning_rate]
To sum it up in my mind when you call train_step tensorflow runs `tf.add(global_step,1)`

Comment: Hi Jean, thanks for the reply. I included the related code in the original post.

Comment: Your code looks ok are you sure you are monitoring learning_rate_node if you wanna see it decrease ?

Comment: I will add a working example with your optimizer when I will have time in my answer.

Comment: Hi Jean, I also asked a question regarding the global step information, which is also related to this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40579722/regarding-setting-the-global-step-information-in-mini-batch-optimization   Would you like to take a look at it, and any insight will be appreciated.

Comment: I had a look I will post an answer either tomorrow or this week-end.

Comment: or at least I will write what I know about the internals of tensorflow but do not expect too much!

Comment: Hi Jean, very clear example. Thank yo so much. So according to your comments, #I see the train_step as implicitely executing sess.run(tf.add(global_step,1)),     Tensorflow has an inherent mechanism to automatically increase the global_step, which should be the same as step. Is that right?

Comment: Yes it is how I see it. Not sure if this is exactly how it is implemented though but you can see it like this.