# regarding setting the global step information in mini-batch optimization

Tags: python, tensorflow

In the [MNIST example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/mnist/convolutional.py), the optimizer is setup as follows

```
# Optimizer: set up a variable that's incremented once per batch and
# controls the learning rate decay.
  batch = tf.Variable(0, dtype=data_type())
# Decay once per epoch, using an exponential schedule starting at 0.01.
  learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(
      0.01,                # Base learning rate.
      batch * BATCH_SIZE,  # Current index into the dataset.
      train_size,          # Decay step.
      0.95,                # Decay rate.
      staircase=True)
  # Use simple momentum for the optimization.
   optimizer = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate,
                                     0.9).minimize(loss,
                                                   global_step=batch)
```

And in the training process,

```
for step in xrange(int(num_epochs * train_size) // BATCH_SIZE):

    # skip some code here
    sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

My question is that when defining `learning_rate`, they use `batch * batch_size`to define global step. However, in the training iteration, we only have variable step. How does the code connect(or pass) the step information to the global step parameter in `tf.train.exponential_decay`  I am not very clear how does this python parameter passing mechanism work.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you have linked, `batch` *is* the global step. Its value is updated by the optimizer. The learning node takes it as input.

The naming may be an issue. `batch` merely means the number of the current batch used for training (of size `BATCH_SIZE`). Perhaps a better name could have been `step` or even `global_step`.

Most of the `global_step` code seems to be [in a single source file](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/training_util.py). It is quite short and perhaps a good way to see how the pieces work together.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I still feel confused. in sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict=feed_dict). it will call the definiation of optimizer, which includes (Batch). I think it need some mechanism to pass the step inforamtion to Batch(or Global_step). But I did not see how it does?